# PHPUnit override mock "willReturn()" statement

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, reset, spy

I'm having an issue with PHPUnit mocks, when I call method()->willReturn() on the second time it seems to maintain the first value defined on setUp:

```php
<?php

namespace Test\Application\UseCase;

use Application\UseCase\CreateFoo;
use Application\Exceptions\RequiredValueException;
use Domain\Entity\Foo;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class CreateFooTest extends TestCase
{
    private CreateFoo $sut;
    private Foo $foo_spy;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->foo_spy = $this->createMock(Foo::class);
        $this->foo_spy->method('getBar')->willReturn('bar value');
        $this->foo_spy->method('getBaz')->willReturn('baz value');

        $this->sut = new CreateFoo;
    }

    public function test_assert_given_foo_without_bar_throws_exception()
    {
        // Arrange
        $this->expectException(RequiredValueException::class);
        $this->expectExceptionMessage('Missing Bar value.');
        $this->expectExceptionCode(500);

        $this->foo_spy->method('getBar')->willReturn(null);

        // var_dump($this->foo_spy->getBar());
        // outputs: string(bar value)
        // expected: null


        // Act, Assert
        $this->sut->execute($foo_spy);
    }

    public function test_assert_given_foo_without_baz_throws_exception()
    {
        // Arrange
        $this->expectException(RequiredValueException::class);
        $this->expectExceptionMessage('Missing Baz value.');
        $this->expectExceptionCode(500);

        $this->foo_spy->method('getBaz')->willReturn(null);

        // var_dump($this->foo_spy->getBaz());
        // outputs: string(baz value)
        // expected: null

        // Act, Assert
        $this->sut->execute($foo_spy);
    }
}
```

Without defining on the `setUp`, I have to rewrite every test the default value just to test ONE method call like this:

```php
        $this->foo_spy->method('getBar0')->willReturn('bar value 0');
        $this->foo_spy->method('getBar1')->willReturn('bar value 1');
        $this->foo_spy->method('getBar2')->willReturn('bar value 2');
        $this->foo_spy->method('getBar3')->willReturn('bar value 3');
        $this->foo_spy->method('getBaz')->willReturn(null);
```

The problem is: sometimes I have 10 properties or more to test, and it leads to huge unnecessary code duplication, so I would like to write a default spy mock only once and then modify only when necessary, but as you can see when I try to "reset" the method behavior, it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that every time you use `method`, it will create a new matcher.
Since all of them will match, it will always select the first one.

My solution in a similar case was to use a callback:

```php
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->bar_value = 'bar value';
        $this->baz_value = 'baz value';

        $this->foo_spy = $this->createMock(Foo::class);
        $this->foo_spy->method('getBar')->will( $this->returnCallback(function () { return $this->bar_value; } ) );
        $this->foo_spy->method('getBaz')->will( $this->returnCallback(function () { return $this->baz_value; } ) );

        $this->sut = new CreateFoo;
    }
```

Now you can override `$this->bar_value` in the single tests, getting the result that you want.

Answer (score 0):

The `setUp()` function is run before every test* function, maybe `setUpBeforeClass()` is what you're looking for there, that's only run once for all the tests in that file.

To reduce code duplication you could create a helper function to get the mock:

```
public function getFooMock($barReturn = 'bar value', $bazReturn = 'baz value') {
    $mock = $this->createMock(Foo::class);
    $mock->method('getBar')->willReturn($barReturn);
    $mock->method('getBaz')->willReturn($bazReturn);
    return $mock;
}
```

and then use it like so:

```
$this->sut->execute($this->getFooMock('bar value 0', null));
```

That should yield the expected results.

Comment: Writing tests for classes with many dependencies or for functions that call many other functions becomes painful really quickly and if you have control over the code you're testing it might be worth it to refactor.

Comment: It could work if we have a couple of properties, but I'm persisting an entity through a **Use Case**, naturally, it becomes a big method, for example, I have obligatory 10 properties to persist, this solution still duplicating code and complicate the code readability, imagine passing 10 parameters every time, (maybe we can make a factory of a factory to solve this?)